# Blockchain : Hyper Ledger Fabric Installations in Windows 10

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, azure-blockchain-workbench

I have visited almost all the links available for the installation of Hyper Ledger in Windows 10.
I have installed:

1. Git
2. Docker
3. Ubuntu Bash
4. Npm
5. NodeJS

And almost all other things that were mentioned in those links. But at the end of those links, running and installing Hyper Ledger fabric. I get errors of not available binary samples.

Some links that lead me to something, but an error in the end.

[Link1](https://medium.com/@harismumtaz_19503/step-by-step-hyperledger-fabric-installation-on-windows-10-7ad462cea89c)

[Link2](https://www.codementor.io/@hajsf/install-hyperledger-fabric-at-win-10-tb85r9dqg)

**Please, anyone, tell me a way of installing and running Hyper Ledger Fabric on Windows 10. I have to make a Mobile Application on Hyper Ledger Fabric.**

*It will be a blessing for me if someone also can tell me how and using what tool I can make Mobile Application using Hyper Ledger Fabric.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful: Hypereldger Fabric is actually not supported for Windows. You must run it in Linux.

I know there are some guides online but follow the documentation.
While your Java/Python/Go/Node SDK can be run on Windows, the network must be on Linux.
That's not impossible to run it on Windows, but they do not assure you will be able to do this.

Maybe support for Windows will come in next versions.

Comment: Thanks!
Can you please guide me on how to install it in windows environment. By making a ubuntu virtual machine or something? I don't want to uninstall windows.

Comment: Yes you can create a virtual machine using VMware or VirtualBox and run it. I sugget you to use Ubuntu 18.04. Otherwise you can host a Linux machine on Amazon AWS.

Comment: Can you provide me an accurate link? so that I can follow that and create a virtual machine and run hyper ledger on it?

Comment: Also, can I use Ubuntu bash as my virtual machine?

Comment: This would be another question. Please, set my answer as "answer" here on StackOverflow cause it solved your problem. Regarding this one, cannot answer 100% here but essentially you can follow a guide to create a virtual machine for Linux. Once you're done, you can easily follow the Hyperledger Guide cause it's done for Ubuntu 18.04. And you are ready to go like it is your own machine.

Comment: Thanks! I will ask further if required.